# Developer copy of Oracle DB

Tags: oracle

Here is the problem - I have to use remote db for few hours a day. And the VPN we use (for unknown reason) drops Oracle connection several times an hour which is really annoying and time consuming..

The sysadmin who manages both the Sonic VPN and the DB cant help..

So I am thinking to place a db copy locally.

What I need/don't need:

- the all changes on the remote db (the master) should propagate quite easily to the copy (auto or manually - I don't mind as soon as it a one button push). they are rare - once a day at most
- my changes to the local db should not be propagated to the master (but I am flexible here)
- I don't have to spend more than 5 min a day to maintain this
- it would be nice to replicate only DDL from master (I don't need the actual data changes, only tables changes)

**is there a sort of replication or any other solution I can use to achieve this?**

Comment: Sounds like you'd be better off finding out how to change the VPN/firewall/listener/DB setting that is causing the actual problem. Finding out which of those it is not necessarily easy of course, without sysadmin/DBA support. One thing I'd try is connecting to the DB over a port that is tunneled through ssh, with keepalives enabled, if you're able to do that.

Comment: Does it only drop the Oracle part, or your whole VPN connection?  Maybe the problem is a profile that disconnects after X minutes of being idle.  Check `DBA_PROFILES` for the idle disconnect time.  Most IDEs have some way to ping the database to keep the connection alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database Replication isn't cheap. Your company will pay more to build replication environment , starting from the oracle edition and license and many extra.

Replication will  increase the  complexity of the database administration.
Finally, the More important point ,Database replication work in your VPN environment :) (which is disconnected all the time ) and replication will fail all the time.

You can with network team:

- Review the service level agreement (SLA) contract of VPN with the
  service provider to know the percentage of time down and the Quality of service.
- Network administrator monitor network to spot where is the problem-may be line /router/network configuration/network card.
- Do some measures: what the size  of your transaction per minute (in bytes) to select the best speed from the network service provider.
- Measuring Network Bandwidth Using iperf , for ref: https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/measuring_network_bandwidth_using_iperf
- Perform a Network Performance Test

Answer (score 0):

if the changes are once a day your best and easiest solution would be to do a full backup of master db then zip it ftp/email and unzip + restore on your end. But this wont be feasible if the db size is too large.